# How to reset counter and position within window

Tags: javascript

I'm running a tutorial series and have got a project to make.
It's a reaction tester and after lots of googling, I can't seem to solve two problems and hoped for some help.

When you start the game and click on the shape, it outputs time until click, creates random shape, color, size and position.

I'd like to reset the counter after each click on the shape and make sure that the shape never goes out of the window.

As it is right now, it just keeps counting and update with the new count and sometimes, the shape is created outside the window so you have to scroll to find it.

I've tried resetting the `var timeUntilClick = +new Date() - currentTime;` with `var timeUntilClick = "";` without luck

[Here's my code on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/865th8Lk/)

Answer (score 0):

your `currentTime` is defined once when clicked on "start". And you keep substracting it from `new Date()` later. That's why counter increases. You need to reset `currentTime` when creating new shape. [quick JSFiddle forked edit](https://jsfiddle.net/tb86491w/)

Comment: As for  shapes outside window... problem is that you don't take into consideration width and height of the shape when calculating position. Top-left corner point of the shape WILL be inside window, but remaining of the shape can fall out. Your code is confusing, I dont know why you use `randomLeft` for both width of the shape and left position. In case you split it in `randomLeft` and `randomWidth` then deduct `randomWidth` from `window.innerWidth` before randomising `randomLeft` and your shape will fit completely into window (check border too!). Same for height and vertical positioning.

Comment: Thanks, your updated JSFiddle didn't work but found a solution from Mottie on how to reset the counter by using `currentTime = +new Date();`. As for the confusing code, I'm new at this and thought that I could use randomLeft for both width and the left position, but I can see now that your solution will help keeping the shapes inside of the window

Answer (score 0):

Update your currentTime on each click.

```
currentTime += timeUntilClick;
```

And for the position of your shape, a basic solution would be to divide the height and width it can takes.

```
var w = window.innerWidth/2;
var h = window.innerHeight/2;
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/865th8Lk/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.... [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/865th8Lk/3/)

```
document.getElementById("startGame").onclick = function() {

  var currentTime = +new Date();

  document.getElementById("shape").onclick = function() {

    function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (3500 - 500 + 1) + 500);
    }

    function insideWindow(position, dimension, max) {
      if (position + dimension >= max) {
        return max - dimension;
      }
      return position;
    }

    function getRandomColor() {
      var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
      var color = '#';
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
      return color;
    }

    var randomColor = getRandomColor();
    var randomShape = Math.round(Math.random());

    if (randomShape < 0.5) {
      randomShape = "50%";
    } else {
      randomShape = "10%";
    }

    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;

    var randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    var randomTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var randomWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * (w / 2));
    var randomHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * (h / 2));

    var elem = document.getElementById("shape").style;
    elem.backgroundColor = randomColor;
    elem.left = insideWindow(randomLeft, randomWidth, w) + "px";
    elem.top = insideWindow(randomTop, randomHeight, h) + "px";
    elem.borderRadius = randomShape;
    elem.width = randomWidth + "px";
    elem.height = randomHeight + "px";

    document.getElementById("shape").setAttribute("class", "hide");

    var timeUntilClick = +new Date() - currentTime;

    if (timeUntilClick > 999) {
      var timeUntilClick = timeUntilClick / 1000 + " seconds";
    } else {
      var timeUntilClick = timeUntilClick + " milliseconds";
    }

    document.getElementById("printTime").innerHTML = timeUntilClick;

    var randomDelay = randomIntFromInterval();

    setTimeout(delay, randomIntFromInterval());

    function delay() {
      document.getElementById("shape").removeAttribute("class", "hide");
      currentTime = +new Date();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, `currentTime = +new Date();` was a great solution for resetting the counter